# None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

Tags: c#, autofac

When I try to set a PARAMETER using the Xml Configuration I get the following error:

> *None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'LM.AM.Core.Services.EmailService' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'System.String
>   testSmtp' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String)'.*

Here are the relevant files:

**web.config**

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="autofac" type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration" />
  </configSections>

  <autofac>
    <components>
      <component type="LM.AM.Core.Services.EmailService , LM.AM.Core" service="LM.AM.Core.Infrastructure.Services.IEmailService , LM.AM.Core.Infrastructure">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="testSmtp" value="abc" />
        </parameters>
      </component>
    </components>
  </autofac>
```

**Service Class**

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public string _testSmtp;

    public EmailService (string testSmtp)
    {
        _testSmtp = testSmtp;
    }
}
```

**Registration**

```
builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>().SingleInstance();
```

**Global.asax**

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));

builder.RegisterModule<Core.ModuleInstaller>();

builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
AutofacContainer.Container = builder.Build();

var emailSvc = AutofacContainer.Container.Resolve<IEmailService>();
```

I've checked the container is aware of the xml parameter and I've followed the Wiki as close as I can, but for some reason the parameter is not resolving on the only constructor and I'm receiving the above error.

This should be pretty simple to get going. Can anyone provide some suggestions on what I 
can try to get this working?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have regiestered your `EmailService` **two times.**

Once in the web.config and once with

```
builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>().SingleInstance();
```

If you have the line above in the `Core.ModuleInstaller` then **it will override the web.config configuration.** And because here you haven't specified the parameter Autofac throws an exception.

So to solve this **just remove the `EmailService` registration** from the `Core.ModuleInstaller` module.

If you use the `Core.ModuleInstaller` multiple places and you need to have the `EmailService` registration there then you need to change the order of the Module loading:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule<Core.ModuleInstaller>();
builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
```

or tell `Autofac` to not override the registration of `EmailService` if it already exists with `PreserveExistingDefaults`:

```
builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>()
       .SingleInstance().PreserveExistingDefaults();
```

Answer (score 8):

I had created a constructor where there was none before and made it private, therefore there was default constructor so I got this error. Had to make my constructor public.

Answer (score 1):

My registrations were all good, but I had referenced the concrete class instead of the interface in my constructor - Missed the 'I'.
Hope this answer helps someone save 5 minutes of effort one day.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the service with appropriate scope(Singleton,Scoped,Transient) to the specified IServiceCollection instance helped to resolve this issue.
Something like below:

```
public static IServiceCollection YourServiceCollectionExtensionMethod(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer seems to be unrelated to autofac and the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and it turned out I was not using the Interface type in the constructor.  For example,

Not using constructor params as Interface (Bad):

```cs
namespace Acme.Services
    {
       public class MyWebHookHandler : IMyWebHookHandler
       {
         private readonly HttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

         public MyWebHookHandler(HttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory)
         {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
         }
    }
 }
```

Using constructor params as Interface (Good):

```cs
namespace Acme.Services
    {
       public class MyWebHookHandler : IMyWebHookHandler
       {
         private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

         public MyWebHookHandler(IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory)
         {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You know that this question was answered over 10 years ago?